# LINQ: How to refresh a GridView bound to LinqDataSource?

Tags: asp.net, linq, gridview, linqdatasource

I retrieve keywords from a textbox and want to refresh a GridView that is bound to a LinqDataSource.

I assume I can do this in the OnTextChanged function as follows

```
    protected void OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     // do LINQ query based on content in textbox
     catalogDataContext dc = new catalogDataContext();
     var query = from product in dc.catalog
                 where product.Name.Contains(TextBox.Text)
                 select product;     

     // what do I have to do here to refresh the GridView? Thanks.


    GridView.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Did you try it? It worked, right?

Answer (score 0):

Use your linq source's databind method to refresh data context first. Then use gridView's databind method to refresh grid view to new context. 
TIP: if you want, put your gridView in AJAX update panel - the resulting page is much better that way.